# Cast V3 not showing Android TV device on network

Tags: android, google-cast

I have a Nexus Player on my network.

I am updating my Android App to use Google Cast V3. I have published a receiver.  When I launch my app and attempt to connect to a Cast device, I only see my Chromecast devices on the network. The Nexus Player does not show up in the dialog as an option to select.

It would appear that the Receiver in the Cast Developer Console is still only seeing the test Chromecast devices, even though the Receiver is published.

Is there further configuration, possibly in the Android Manifest, that needs to be performed to allow connecting to via Google Cast to an Android TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was impatient.  I didn't give the Nexus Player enough time between testing my app and the publishing completed.